# Copy "two specific sheets" into a new workbook

Tags: vba, excel, copy

When we have a workbook with several sheets

```
sheet_1, sheet_2, ..., sheet_n, sheet_constant
```

and we like to create n workbooks with pairs of two sheets

```
workbook 1: sheet_1, sheet_constant
workbook 2: sheet_2, sheet_constant
...
workbook n: sheet_n, sheet_constant
```

how can we do this with vba?

I know we can copy one sheet with this

```
Sub CopySheet()
  ThisWorkbook.Sheets("sheet_1").Copy
  Application.Dialogs(xlDialogSaveAs).Show
End Sub
```

And I tried this with no success

```
Sub CopySheets()
  ThisWorkbook.Sheets("sheet_1").Copy
  ThisWorkbook.Sheets("sheet_constant").Copy
  Application.Dialogs(xlDialogSaveAs).Show
End Sub
```

Comment: this is a recurring task and specific for other use cases. Did research and found only solutions for one sheet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

```
Sub CopySheets(VariableSheetName As String, ConstantSheetName As String)
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets(Array(VariableSheetName, _
                              ConstantSheetName)).Copy
    Application.Dialogs(xlDialogSaveAs).Show
End Sub
```

Note: Copying both sheets at once has the advantage that any references between the sheets won't suddenly become links to the original workbook, which is what could happen if you copy the sheets one after the other.

This subroutine can be called as:

```
CopySheets "sheet_1", "sheet_constant"
CopySheets "sheet_2", "sheet_constant"
CopySheets "sheet_3", "sheet_constant"
```

or in a loop (assuming your sheets do have numbers in them)

```
For i = 1 To 3
    CopySheets "sheet_" & i, "sheet_constant"
Next
```

or, if you want all sheets copied:

```
For Each ws in Worksheets
    If ws.Name <> "sheet_constant" Then
        CopySheets ws.Name, "sheet_constant"
    End If
Next
```

Comment: This would work exactly the way he'd like if you added a parameter to `Sub CopySheets(intSheet as Integer)` and then changed the first array element to `intSheet` from `"Sheet_1"`

Comment: @dbmitch - thanks for the suggestion - I've edited my answer to pass **both** sheets as parameters.  (It's probably more intuitive to any subsequent user of gco's application if they can look at the calling code and see both sheets being mentioned.)

Answer (score 0):

Based on @YowE3K answer, this one is a little more generic and hase autoSave option.

```
Sub CopySheets()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    ChDir (ThisWorkbook.Path)
    For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        If ws.Name = "sheet_constant" Then GoTo NextIteration
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets(Array(ws.Name, "sheet_constant")).Copy
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=ws.Name, FileFormat:=xlNormal, CreateBackup:=False
        ActiveWorkbook.Saved = True
        ActiveWindow.Close
        Application.DisplayAlerts = True
        Application.ScreenUpdating = True
NextIteration:
    Next ws

End Sub
```

Comment: The use of `i` in that code will cause problems unless "sheet_constant" is the last sheet processed in the loop.  You can fix it by using `ThisWorkbook.Sheets(Array(ws.Name, "sheet_constant")).Copy`.  (You can probably also fix it by moving the `i = i + 1` after the label, but there is no need for the `i` anyway, so it is easier to just get rid of it.)